# How many ways there are to choose 5 Disjoint sets from a set of 10 Elements?

Tags: combinatorics

Note : Set can be empty, and "Order type between the chosen sets is matters".
Because of that every set size from the 5 can be with different or equal size it confusing me.

"Order type between the chosen sets is matters" - we need to take into consideration all the different options - For example, We have the chosen sets A,B,C,D,E. So we need to take in our option the option when A is from size 1 and B is from size 2, an also when A from size 2 and B is from size 1.

Edit : The order of sets doesn't matter.

Comment: What does "Order type is matters" mean?  Are the sets you choose labeled in some way?

Comment: In spite of your edit it is still not clear what is mean by "Order type between the chosen sets is matters". Are the 5 sets required to be distinct? Is $(\varnothing,\varnothing,\varnothing,\varnothing,\varnothing)$ an option for instance?

Comment: Can  you edit your post for clarity?  If not, I think it should  be closed.

Comment: *Disjoint* is not the same as *distinct*. The sets $\varnothing$ and $\varnothing$ are not distinct, but they are disjoint. Simply because $\varnothing\cap\varnothing=\varnothing$. With that they obey the definition of being disjoint.

Comment: @drhab yes, the chosen groups need to be disjoint, as I described.

Comment: @lulu I clarified the meaning of "Order type is matters"

Comment: You did not answer my question: are they demanded to be **distinct** (as said something else than disjoint)?

Comment: You have not clarified anything. do the order of the sets matter?  If I take an acceptable selection and I switch the first two sets do I get a new selection?

Comment: @lulu the order of the sets doesn't matter, edited.

Comment: @drhab they are need to be disjoint (from my understanding of disjoint definition). Anyway, It needs to be according to this example : (1 2), (3 4) are disjoint sets, but (1 2) (2 3) are not disjoint sets.

Comment: Do you understand the distinction between "disjoint" and "distinct"?  Is $\{\emptyset, \emptyset,\emptyset,\emptyset,\emptyset\}$ a good selection or not?  The sets are obviously disjoint.

Comment: @lulu yes {∅,∅,∅,∅,∅} is good selection after I saw the definition.

Comment: Well, to get you started:  it's (a lot) easier to do the problem if the order of the sets does matter.  In that case we have five labeled subsets $S_1,\cdots, S_5$ and let's introduce $S_6$ to hold the elements which aren't in any of the five chosen subsets. Then each of the $10$ elements has exactly six options, so the answer is just $6^{10}$.  Now you need to consider the permutations of the arrangements, but care must be taken since two or more of the $S_i$ might be the empty set.

Comment: @lulu thank you!